# jQuery Toggling next row in dynamically created table with dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a  jQuery dynamically created table that appends data  from json file.
one of the rows of the table is a row of buttons that are appended into a row variable that is appended into the table:

```
var like = $("<a href='index.html'><button class='likeBtn'>like</button></a>");

var comment = $("<a href='index.html'><button class='comBtn'>comment</button></a>");

var toggle = $("<a href='index.html'><button class='togBtn'>show/hide comments</button></a>");

row3.append(like).buttonset();
row3.append(comment).buttonset();
row3.append(toggle).buttonset();

$("#table").append(row3);
```

now I need to toggle the row below in the table when clicking the toggle button.
this is my onclick function:

```
$(function(){
    alert("in");
      $('.togBtn').click(function() {
          alert("in2");
          $(this).closest('tr').toggle();

      });
    });
```

when I put alerts inside the click function I don't see them, I do see alerts from the function that holds the click function. for example- I see "in" but I don't see "in2".

and of course the row is not toggled.
commentRow is the class of the row that needs to be toggled.
I tried lots of options like-

```
 $("#table").closest('.commentRow').toggle();
```

also with next() , All(), and many others and I can't get it to work!!!

please - your thoughts on this.
All help will be much appreciated!

Comment: On dynamically created elements you do not use click() you are to use on()

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the dynamically generated content, try that:

```
$(document).on('click','.togBtn',function(e) {
   alert("in2");
   $(this).closest('tr').toggle();
   // or return false; // it does both preventDefault & stopPropagation.
});
```

---

This is called `event delegation`. This technique is only used when you have generated dynamic DOM nodes like as you are doing in your code.
So, in this case all the events were bound when page was initially loaded and the elements are generated after page load, due to that browser didn't registered any event for those elements because of unavailablity. In this case event has to be delegated to the static parent node or to the `document` itself because it is always available.

Syntax for event delegation using `.on()` method:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, cb);
```

Comment: It finally does something!!! it shows the alert , but then it toggles the button row , refreshes the page automatically and everything is back to normal.

Comment: ok now it toggles the comment!!! but- it refreshes the page and  shows it again. how can I stop it from refreshing?

Comment: update- I added e.preventDefault()  now it does not refresh the page but now it hides the button line instead of the comment line

Comment: Update! resolved:  I used $(this).parents("tr").next().slideToggle(); and it works!! Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the answers posted here I found a solution that works:

```
$(document).on('click','.togBtn',function(e) {
       alert("in2");
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parents("tr").next().slideToggle();
       // or return false; // it does both preventDefault & stopPropagation.
    });
```

Thanks all for your help!